# Not closed under equality?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations, closed-form

One of the Peano axioms state that

"For any $a \in \Bbb N : a = b, b \in \Bbb N$."

An example where transition is not closed under equality is the relation to friends. C may not be B's friend, but A may be B's friend, even though A isn't C's friend; that is : A = B =/= C.

Is there any case for any set (not limited to $\Bbb N$) where the set is not closed under equality, that is, it produces a member from another set? I would assume this to mean "open" (not in the topological definition), but correct me if I am wrong.

From Wikipedia: For all a and b, if a is a natural number and a = b, then b is also a natural number. That is, the natural numbers are closed under equality

Comment: Not under the common definition of equality as finest equivalence relation. As a matter of fact, I am not used to seeing your axiom among the Peano axioms. Instead, equality $x=y$ is understood as $P(x)\leftrightarrow P(y)$ for arbitrary predicates $P$.

Comment: I'd be careful about using the word 'open' to mean 'not closed'. In maths they often mean different things.

Comment: I forgot to add that Clive; thanks.

Comment: I don't recall this axiom.

Comment: @AsafKaragila see edit

Comment: You need to read that axiom in its historical context. It was before logic was developed to its current form. Today everything is closed under equality; but back in 1879 things were different.

Comment: Thanks! I'll keep this in mind.

Comment: Also, note that the "is friends with" relation is not the equality relation, since it is (as you've noted) not a transitive relation, so not an equivalence relation, so not the equality relation (the finest equivalence relation). However, the "is friends with" relation **is** closed under equality. If Alice is friends with Bob, and Alice's nickname is Ally (so Alice=Ally), then Ally is friends with Bob, since "Alice" and "Ally" are simply two different names for the same person.